# Problem with calling SESSION in another php tag

Tags: php, html

So I'm trying to call the SESSION from one < ?php ?> (had to add the space cause it didn't want to show it) tag, in another < ?php ?> tag and I've no idea why it's not working at all. What I'm trying to do is to show the "editPassword" of an added advertisement in an alert modal window. But the problem is, that I'm getting an error, like the SESSION doesn't exist. The echo underneath the $post was only done to try if it works correctly in this php tag. It does.

```
    
  $postData = [
      'title' => $_POST['title'],
      'content' => $_POST['content'],
      'imageName' => $_FILES['imageUpload']['name'],
      'imageTmpName' => $_FILES['imageUpload']['tmp_name'],
      'imageSize' => $_FILES['imageUpload']['size'],
      'brand'   => $_POST["brand"],
      'model'   => $_POST["model"],
      'type'   => $_POST["type"],
      'fueltype'  => $_POST["fueltype"],
      'price'  => $_POST["price"],
      'editPassword' => $_SESSION['editPassword'] = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 5)
  ];
   $post->addPost($connection, $postData);
   echo $_SESSION['editPassword'];
}?>
```

And I'm calling the SESSION again in the html with a simple:

```
<p><?php  echo $_SESSION['editPassword']?></p>
```

When I try to run it, it shows this error, like the SESSION doesn't exist.
[ERROR SHOWN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s5Cr.png)

And when I fill the form the second time without reloading the page, it runs fine, BUT it shows the editPassword for the previous advert, not the current one.

[editPassword of previous advert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVp5k.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I've added the `session_start();` at the beginning of the php, now there's another problem which I've specified in the comments.

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()` at the top of your PHP code?

Comment: I'm not, but I tried it, and it makes no difference.

Edit: It works after adding it, BUT it still only shows the editPassword of the previous advert, not the current one.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular https://imgur.com/a/1afFNKf
As you can see, it's not showing the editPassword of the newest advertisement.

Comment: Please share more details, like the error messages in text form and your attempts to resolve them.

Comment: After adding the session_start(); there are no error messages present. The problem is with the $_SESSION showing the editPassword for the previous advertisement, instead of the one I've just created.

Comment: So I think I know where the problem lies, but I still don't know how to resolve it. I'm calling the `session_start ()` at the beginning of the php, (So before the new advertisement was created) BUT the session that I need is the one AFTER I've created the new advertisement.

Comment: That last comment doesn't make much sense. You don't have two different sessions (assuming your session is working correctly to begin with, and there isn't a new session-ID created on every request) - you have _one_ session. And if you see "old" data in there at a point where you expected it to be "new" data instead - then you probably must have some logical error in your flow somewhere.

Comment: Yeah it figures.. I just woke up feeling smart, but it wasn't even close.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason $_SESSION['editPassword'] doesn't have a default value, that might trigger an undefined index until this runs, which i suppose doesn't run until a form is submitted.
So what you could do is

```
if (isset($_SESSION['editPassword'])){
echo $_SESSION['editPassword'];
}
```

You might also what to put a condition over when the form is submitted, something like

```
if (isset($_POST['submit])){
echo $_SESSION['editPassword'];
}
```

or read on $_REQUEST

Comment: The first option does the same thing, it shows the previous advertisement editPassword.
And the second one doesn't show anything.

Comment: session_start() on both pages requiring editPassword

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: lets assume you've got file A and B
in File A, you're creating a session variable,
at the top of file A, do session_start()
then assign the variable you want as you've done above.
In File B, also do session_start() at the top then you can echo any session variable existing in the current session

Comment: Tips: do not forget to sanitize you POST variable against injection before sending it into the DB

Comment: It's actually only one file. Both of these "sessions" are in the AddAdvert.php file.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to give me more details about your code. Maybe with the modal part in an online editor

Comment: `<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  id="confirmPass">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="card-title" title="Generate"></h5>
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><?php echo $_SESSION['editPassword'];?></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`

Comment: $post->addPost($connection, $postData); what happens in addPost method?

Comment: I'm gonna copy the entire file for you since it's a pretty long method. https://eubask-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/mlukac2_student_euba_sk/Eb5d-ZItIW1PkDdRZuV9_hwB1XkcCZ6IDt8TqDB4FeltAA?e=8l9zVL

Comment: It basically just inserts the data into the database. The problem is with getting the "editPassword" out of the database. It basically doesn't show the password of the latest advertisement, but the one posted before it. Maybe there's an easier way of doing this than using the $_SESSION, like using the getPosts method in the insertClass.php to select the "editPassword" value but I've already tried it and it ended up in tons of errors...

Comment: You need session_start() at top of your php file, https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: @Grumpy you are stating the obvious